# In aPython Dataframe, How do I match the first event based on the date for each unique id and capture that specific event?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, time-series, data-manipulation

In Python, I  have a data frame with ids and many event dates and type of events. I want to find the first event for each id and create a new column stating that date and another create another column for their first type of event.

```
  event_id  date    typeofevent
        e0 2015-07-20   1
        e0 2015-07-25   4
        e1 2015-06-02   2
        e1 2015-07-18   1
        e1 2015-07-20   3
        e2 2015-04-25   2
        e2 2015-07-28   2
        e2 2015-06-20   3
        e2 2015-05-25   4
```

df['first_event'] = df.groupby(['event_id'])['date'].first()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As those dates follow the pattern `YYYY-MM-DD`, a simple `min()` inside a `groupby()` would work. It would take the minimum date of each `event_id`. Then you could `merge()` them.

Input:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'event_id': ['e0', 'e0', 'e1', 'e1', 'e1', 'e2', 'e2', 'e2', 'e2'],
    'date': [
        '2015-07-20', '2015-07-25', '2015-06-02', '2015-07-18', '2015-07-20',
        '2015-04-25', '2015-07-28', '2015-06-20', '2015-05-25'
    ],
    'typeofevent': [1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4]})

temp_df = df.groupby('event_id').agg({'date': 'min'}).reset_index()

df = df.merge(temp_df, on='event_id')

df.rename(columns={'date_x': 'date', 'date_y': 'first'}, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
  event_id        date  typeofevent       first
0       e0  2015-07-20            1  2015-07-20
1       e0  2015-07-25            4  2015-07-20
2       e1  2015-06-02            2  2015-06-02
3       e1  2015-07-18            1  2015-06-02
4       e1  2015-07-20            3  2015-06-02
5       e2  2015-04-25            2  2015-04-25
6       e2  2015-07-28            2  2015-04-25
7       e2  2015-06-20            3  2015-04-25
8       e2  2015-05-25            4  2015-04-25
```

Comment: How would i make an additional new column with that type of event that also occurred that day. example df['first_event'] was type 1,2 or 3 etc.